# Stretch div dependence of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want stretch box dependence of content, i'm using flexbox, but i can't to do. Below link my example

```
Parent div 

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;

Child div 

  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
```

```css
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.sliderItem {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sliderItemTitle {      
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  min-height: 84px;
}
.sliderItemText {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  min-height: 58px;
  align-items: center;
}
.sliderItemLinkBox {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.sliderItemLink {
  color: yellow;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">

  <div class="slick-slide">
    <div> 
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 1</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          lorema dadad addadadad adadadadadasd
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slide">
    <div> 
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 2</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          Lorem 
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slide">
    <div> 
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 3</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dolore ipsa at minus molestias, neque rerum, aut minima voluptatum, dolorem odit nesciunt aliquid ullam officia reiciendis, recusandae natus maxime beatae.
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7qvo2tmk/5/

Comment: *"I want stretch box dependence of content..."* what do you mean ?

Comment: @ths Please see jsfiddle link, example code there

Comment: do you want all the 3 areas to have the same height ?

Comment: @ths yes, absolutely right, dependence of content box should have same height

Comment: @ths can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using JS to loop through the elements and adjust the height based on the tallest element.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/abge7r0f/1/)

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderItem')

function updateHeights() {
  let tallestSlide = 0
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if (slides[i].clientHeight > tallestSlide) {
        tallestSlide = slides[i].clientHeight
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.height = tallestSlide + 'px'
  }

}

window.onresize = updateHeights
updateHeights()
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but i want use only flexbox, because my project on React, i don't want write any js code for this issue, have you any idea about css ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this.

What I did is that I remove the `div` that encloses the `.sliderItem`
and then add height to the `.sliderItem` of `height:100%`. so that it will occupy the height of its parent div `.slick-slide`.

```css
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.sliderItem {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sliderItemTitle {      
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  min-height: 84px;
}
.sliderItemText {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  min-height: 58px;
  align-items: center;
}
.sliderItemLinkBox {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.sliderItemLink {
  color: yellow;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">

  <div class="slick-slide">
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 1</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          lorema dadad addadadad adadadadadasd
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slide">
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 2</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          Lorem 
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slide">
      <div class="sliderItem">
        <div class="sliderItemImg">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemTitle">
           <strong>Title 3</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemText">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dolore ipsa at minus molestias, neque rerum, aut minima voluptatum, dolorem odit nesciunt aliquid ullam officia reiciendis, recusandae natus maxime beatae.
        </div>
        <div class="sliderItemLinkBox">
          <div class="sliderItemLink">
            click
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps